# py.test fixtures with global scope

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures

I am looking for a way to use something like "global fixtures" in `py.test`. It seems that `scope="session"` would be closest to what I need, but it seems it works similarly to a `scope="module"` level option. The fixture is initiated total of `n` times, where `n` is the number of modules.

Basically, I have this slow-to-initialize and resource hungry service that does morphological analysis

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def morfanalyzer():
    from myapp.nlp.morfservice import MorfAnalyzerService
    morfservice = MorfAnalyzerService()

    def f():
        morfservice.run(debug=True)

    thread = Thread(target=f)
    thread.start()

    yield morfservice

    morfservice.stop()
    thread.join()
```

And I use it like

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures(morfanalyzer.__name__)
def test_this_stage(morfanalyzer):
    assert False
```

What I would like to have is that exactly one copy of the service would be spun up before running all the tests and teared down after everything has run.

Comment: Cannot reproduce (using a dummy `HTTPServer` instead of your service). Can you provide a [mcve]? Btw, you are explicitly requesting the fixture value in test (via test arg), so setting `autouse` to `True` and marking the test with `usefixtures` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying `scope="session"` in your fixture, you will have a session-scoped instance.
You can check the setup and teardown of fixtures with the `setup-show` cli flag as reflected in the 3.0 [Changelog](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html?highlight=setup-show#id483)

Also as pointed out by @hoefling in the comments, once set `autouse=True` marking the test with `usefixtures` is not needed anymore.